# axis client stub Calendar wrong date

Tags: java, calendar, axis, stub

i'm having a strange issue.

Using eclipse i generate a stub using a wsdl.

The stub generated accept as parameter a java object in which i need to set a Calendar.

i've got a date in format "yyyy-MM-dd" for example:

```
"2015-02-03"
```

To set Calendar to pass to the stub i use:

```
String arrival[]  = "2015-02-03".split("-");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(arrival[0]), Integer.parseInt(arrival[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(arrival[2]),0,0,0);
```

And to call stub:

```
StubBean bean = new StubBean(calendar,...);
stub.method(bean);
String xml_request  = stub._getCall().getMessageContext().getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString();
System.out.println(xml_request);
```

If i print the soap xml request i notice that the date is :

```
<ArrivalDate>2015-02-02T23:00:00.244Z</ArrivalDate>
```

So one hour before the date i provide.

How can i solve that strange issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: No one.. i'm using the same code

Comment: No, I mean where in the world are you located? Or more specifically, what timezone is the computer that is producing this result set to use as its default timezone?

Comment: It'using Europe/Paris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This is going to produce a calendar object using the host computer's default timezone.

```
<ArrivalDate>2015-02-02T23:00:00.244Z</ArrivalDate>
```

This time is in UTC (the "Z" at the end means "Zulu", aka UTC).

You've indicated the computer is using the time zone for Paris, which is [one hour ahead of UTC](http://24timezones.com/world_directory/time_in_paris.php). In other words, when it's Midnight, Feb. 3 in Paris, it's 23:00, Feb 2 in UTC.

You can initialize the calendar to use UTC instead:

```
TimeZone tzUTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(tzUTC);
```